# Bootstrap 3. Split main section between 2 side sections when shrinking screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

How do I design my bootstrap layout so that side sections will appear next to the main section normally, but then when breaking to a smaller view have the main section split between them. As shown in the pictures below.

[image: large view]

[image: small view]

Comment: This design is rather difficult with bootstrap. Not sure if it's ideal for your situation, but a possible solution would be to have two columns (Left and Right) with section 2 in both but show/hide depending on the browser width. When you hit the small view, you can hide the right column completely, and show the section 2 within the left column. When you jump out of small size, you hide the section two on the left, and show the right column.

Comment: Another approach is using javascript or jQuery to move the sections around to the appropriate place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to display an element between two others on certain screen widths, and place it somewhere else in the page on different widths, you have three courses of action:

1. Display it in both places and hide each using appropriate `@media` queries. Not particularly subtle or elegant, but very effective, since it requires minimal coding. However, if your element has considerable size (i.e: is the main content) it's a really bad solution, since it can almost double your page size.
2. Move the element around in DOM, using a `JavaScript` function triggered on window `resize` event. This is usually acceptable, since it adds a lot of flexibility (no layout/CSS constraints or challenges, whatsoever).
3. If possible, make the three elements siblings and reorder them using `CSS`. This is the best solution, but not always possible.

However, in your case, the third solution is achievable:

The first step is to render your desired layout with three siblings (using `CSS`), instead of grouping two of them in a Bootstrap column. You need to switch from the normal Bootstrap layout of

```
row
  col-sm-4
    1. red
    3. green
  col-sm-8
    2. yellow
```

to:

```
row 
  col-sm-8 {float:right} 
    2. yellow 
  col-sm-4 
    1. red    
  col-sm-4 {clear:left} 
    3. green
```

The above goes for devices wider than `768px`. Since we're working with colored divs, I also added the negative margin hack for making both `.green` and `.yellow` divs fill up the remaining space in the `.row` (depending on which one is longer), but this is totally optional.

Why are we making them siblings? So we could reorder them on narrower screens, using `flexbox`'s `order` property.

Here goes code:

```css
.red {
  background-color: #E81829;
}
.green {
  background-color: #24AA4A;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: #FDC32D;
}
.mySpecialRow > * >p:first-child:first-letter {
  font-size: 4.2rem;
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
  float: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mySpecialRow {
    overflow: hidden; 
  }
  .mySpecialRow .yellow {
    float: right;
  }
  .mySpecialRow .yellow, .mySpecialRow .green {
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
  }
  .mySpecialRow .green {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .mySpecialRow {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .yellow {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
  .green {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mySpecialRow">
    <div class="col-sm-8 yellow">
      <p>2Pinterest brunch meh normcore. Umami quinoa cray, paleo plaid tousled hoodie hella hammock authentic cliche beard. Chillwave bitters master cleanse, celiac authentic pitchfork microdosing truffaut mustache vice portland distillery skateboard 3 wolf moon butcher. Banh mi keytar disrupt heirloom, retro selvage slow-carb 8-bit before they sold out. Chartreuse post-ironic everyday carry viral banjo dreamcatcher beard, you probably haven't heard of them craft beer trust fund mixtape authentic VHS cardigan. Crucifix messenger bag biodiesel, fixie pork belly ugh dreamcatcher kinfolk vice roof party twee paleo franzen leggings. Yuccie wayfarers jean shorts semiotics try-hard craft beer mustache, synth forage brunch asymmetrical.</p>
      <p>Gastropub blog small batch, +1 keytar lomo mumblecore aesthetic. Authentic affogato meggings master cleanse, blue bottle 8-bit church-key tumblr shoreditch occupy readymade photo booth raw denim. Typewriter truffaut retro, shabby chic heirloom letterpress pitchfork four loko offal distillery fap drinking vinegar cold-pressed. Chillwave trust fund small batch dreamcatcher hammock single-origin coffee deep v meditation, tattooed portland fanny pack fixie wayfarers try-hard. Austin +1 mustache, waistcoat paleo stumptown blue bottle kombucha fashion axe raw denim pinterest shabby chic iPhone vinyl. Tattooed pug viral celiac. Fixie helvetica food truck affogato, offal scenester fashion axe.</p>
      <p>Gastropub blog small batch, +1 keytar lomo mumblecore aesthetic. Authentic affogato meggings master cleanse, blue bottle 8-bit church-key tumblr shoreditch occupy readymade photo booth raw denim. Typewriter truffaut retro, shabby chic heirloom letterpress pitchfork four loko offal distillery fap drinking vinegar cold-pressed. Chillwave trust fund small batch dreamcatcher hammock single-origin coffee deep v meditation, tattooed portland fanny pack fixie wayfarers try-hard. Austin +1 mustache, waistcoat paleo stumptown blue bottle kombucha fashion axe raw denim pinterest shabby chic iPhone vinyl. Tattooed pug viral celiac. Fixie helvetica food truck affogato, offal scenester fashion axe.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 red">
      <p>1Hella twee portland selvage, chicharrones tilde small batch. Wayfarers waistcoat stumptown you probably haven't heard of them quinoa, authentic marfa cronut aesthetic single-origin coffee fixie 3 wolf moon migas franzen. You probably haven't heard of them mixtape microdosing letterpress fingerstache before they sold out. 3 wolf moon keytar kale chips fixie, put a bird on it yuccie slow-carb street art hashtag green juice franzen kickstarter post-ironic. Bushwick franzen kickstarter taxidermy  pickled scenester +1 kitsch, seitan occupy normcore brooklyn kinfolk. Migas pop-up bitters hammock. Knausgaard kale chips occupy, tacos iPhone truffaut fanny pack wolf yr.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 green">
      <p>3Street art cred godard normcore. Etsy tousled 3 wolf moon fashion axe try-hard. Four loko 3 wolf moon shoreditch, bespoke trust fund pug artisan gentrify seitan DIY literally selvage PBR&B pork belly kickstarter. Paleo jean shorts thundercats, butcher literally sartorial intelligentsia tacos. Fashion axe tofu YOLO, trust fund flexitarian tattooed mustache yr twee iPhone typewriter mixtape wayfarers cred. Blog art party next level everyday carry hoodie, cardigan iPhone cred yuccie kogi shabby chic meh ennui craft beer farm-to-table. Brunch cliche gastropub austin, paleo cornhole shoreditch jean shorts pabst polaroid.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```